# Marketing Cloud FTP Whitelist

Tags: marketing-cloud, sftp

Is it possible to restrict which IP's can access our Enhanced SFTP in Marketing Cloud?

I know there is an IP whitelist but I think this is only for the UI and API, we need one for our FTP Service to enhance security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATED:

This is now self service through the setup FTP users.

<strike>This can be achieved through a support case. This will need the IP range and the username you want to restrict access to.</strike>

Comment: Setup > Data Management > FTP Accounts > Edit > Allowlist IPs

Comment: Do you know how add IP ranges to allowlist,do I have to add each IP or a range can be added at once. please provide sample for 128.198.1.1 ~ 128.198.1.10, can this be added 128.198.1.1/10?